# FindObjectOfType vs FindFirstObjectByType

Tags: unity

Unity has two functions, with seemingly identical purposes, for finding an object by type.

- [**`Object.FindObjectOfType<T>()`**](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectOfType.html) which has been around forever.

  > The first active loaded object that matches the specified type. It returns null if no Object matches the type.

  There's also an overloaded version which accepts a single boolean argument indicating whether to search inactive objects. `FindObjectOfType<T>(bool includeInactive)` .
- [**`Object.FindFirstObjectByType<T>()`**](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindFirstObjectByType.html) which I think is newer:

  > Returns the first active loaded object that matches the specified type. If no object matches the specified type, returns null.

  There's also an overloaded version which accepts a single enum argument indicating whether to search inactive objects. `FindFirstObjectByType<T>(FindObjectsInactive findObjectsInactive)`;

These functions seem to serve identical purposes, with the only difference between them being that `FindFirstObjectByType()`'s overload (rather pointlessly) takes an enum argument instead of a boolean argument.

**What's the difference between these two functions? Why do both exist?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought of the answer while typing out the question:

There is another new function, `Object.FindAnyObjectByType<T>()` which serves a similar purpose. While `FindFirstObjectByType()` returns the "first" (oldest?) object of the specified type, `FindAnyObjectByType()` doesn't sort in a specific order and is therefore faster.

`FindFirstObjectByType()` is functionally identical to `FindObjectOfType()`; the reason it exists with a new name is to distinguish it from `FindAnyObjectByType()`.

Comment: Personally I think the new option, of returning 'any' rather than 'first', should have been an overload of `FindObjectOfType()`, rather than a new function with a different name. Oh well.

Comment: When there's now a choice of which policy to use, naming the policy you want explicitly in the method name makes a lot of sense. Otherwise you have two very similar looking `FindObjectOfType` calls that do significantly different things, without any hint at the call site about that difference.

Comment: @DMGregory Well, if they're using enums to represent on/off states rather than booleans, they could have something like `public enum SearchMode { First, Any }` and the method call look like `FindObjectOfType<T>(FindObjectsInactive.Include, SearchMode.Any)`

Comment: Now you've added a runtime branch to check the search mode argument if the JIT doesn't inline it, rather than a compile-time choice of overload, reducing the speed boost you got from choosing the fast method in the first place. So that's not an ideal choice for the use case this function was made to serve.

Comment: @DMGregory Fair enough. I use these methods very sparingly and didn't think about the fact that the performance difference will be much more significant for the developers who use these find functions liberally every frame (although I wonder if such developers will notice the new, faster function).

Comment: @DMGregory Just noticed that `FindObjectsByType()` (plural version) works the way I suggested, using an enum to choose the sorting order. It's like they went out of their way to be as confusing and inconsistent as possible.

Comment: In order to return multiple results, they need to iterate the entire list and allocate memory to hold the returned array. That time overhead will dwarf the runtime branch. It's not directly comparable to a case where *none* of that overhead is required by the task being performed, but gets imposed by a bad API choice anyway. You'll notice that even in the `FindObjectsByType` case, they did not re-use the existing `FindObjectsOfType` name with a new overload, so they're acting consistently in both cases, standardizing on a new term "by" - presumably to later deprecate the old "of" versions.